# Setting/Casting specific bits or bytes in a set

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have a 16-bit number, like `0x789A` and I want to change the 2 most significant bits to `10` (setting the highest and clearing the second-highest) to end up with `0x989A`.

I know that I can set the first bit using `n | 0x8000` and I can unset the second bit (in php) using `n & ~0x4000` but is there a way to "cast" the two bits to `10` in one operation without affecting the lesser bits?

Similarly, I have another 16-bit number, like `0xABCD` that I want to change the byte value of the first byte to a different hex value, for instance `5` so that I end up with `0x5BCD`. Is there a way to set bytes using bitwise operations? I'm not even sure how to begin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the 2 most significant bits to binary `10`:

```
0x8000 | ($n & 0x3fff)
```

This will set the most signigicant byte to hex `5`:

```
0x5000 | ($n & 0x0fff)
```

The general idea is that you use 0 bits in the mask to specify the bits you want to replace, 1  to specify the bits to keep, and then OR in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Do it exactly as you had, just do it two bits at a time, e.g

```
(0x789A & ~0xC000) | 0xC000

    0111100010011010   0x789A
  & 0011111111111111  ~0xC000   ---clear the two relevant bits
  ------------------
 =  0011100010011010   0x389A
  | 1000000000000000   0xC000   --- set their new values
  ------------------
 =  1111100010011010   0xF89A
```